# Merging MapReduce output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have two MapReduce jobs which produce files in two separate directories which look like so:

```
 Directory output1:
 ------------------
 /output/20140102-r-00000.txt
 /output/20140102-r-00000.txt
 /output/20140103-r-00000.txt
 /output/20140104-r-00000.txt

 Directory output2:
 ------------------
 /output-update/20140102-r-00000.txt
```

I want to merge these two directories together in a new directory /output-complete/ where the 20140102-r-00000.txt replaces the original file in the /output directory and all of the "-r-0000x" is removed from the file name. The two original directories will now be empty and the resulting directory should look as follows:

```
 Directory output3:
 -------------------
 /output-complete/20140102.txt
 /output-complete/20140102.txt
 /output-complete/20140103.txt
 /output-complete/20140104.txt
```

What is the best way to do this? Can I use only HDFS shell commands? Do I need to create a java program to traverse both directories and do the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pig ...

```
get_data = load '/output*/20140102*.txt' using Loader()
store get_data into "/output-complete/20140102.txt"
```

or HDFS Command...

```
hadoop fs -cat '/output*/20140102*.txt' > output-complete/20140102.txt
```

single qoutes may not work, then try with double quotes

Comment: the 20140102 is not static. It could be anything. I need to store the first eight digits and then have that be the name of the output file something like \d{8}*.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use hdfs command -getMerge for merging hdfs files.